# Update columns in table 1 from columns in table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table:

RatingScore table

columns: id, carid, design, carValue, MadeDate, TestDate

These are my insert values for Rating Score

```
(4,10720654,'Honda1.0_C',09.0000000000000000,'2019-06-20 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-06-20 00:00:00.0000000'),
(4,10720672,'Honda1.0_C',10.8230000000000000,'2019-06-19 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-06-19 00:00:00.0000000'),
(4,10720984,'Honda5.0',38.9250000000000000,'2019-06-18 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-06-18 00:00:00.0000000'),
(4,10720672,'Honda1.0',09.8589000000000000,'2019-06-17 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-06-17 00:00:00.0000000'),
(4,10720672,'Honda1.0',12.6780000000000000,'2019-06-16 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-06-16 00:00:00.0000000')
```

Then I have a table called RatingUpdate

this table has the same columns and these values:

```
(4,10720654,'Honda1.0_C',05.0000000000000000,'2019-06-20 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-08-21 00:00:00.0000000'),
(4,10720672,'Honda1.0_C',06.8000000000000000,'2019-06-19 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-08-21 00:00:00.0000000'),
(4,10720984,'Honda5.0',38.9250000000000000,'2019-06-18 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-08-21 00:00:00.0000000'),
(4,10720672,'Honda1.0',05.9589000000000000,'2019-06-17 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-08-21 00:00:00.0000000'),
(4,10720672,'Honda1.0',11.4570000000000000,'2019-06-16 00:00:00.0000000', '2019-08-21 00:00:00.0000000')
```

I want to update the first table by taking the Carvalues and TestDate from the second table and giving it to the first table. Those in the first table are wrong and this will fix them. I do not want row updated where design is 'Honda5.0' There is many other records in this table this is just a sample. Please provide examples of how I can accomplish this. thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you need but it would be something like:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.design = p.design
    , s.MadeDate = p.MadeDate
    , s.TestDate = p.TestDate
FROM RatingScore s
INNER JOIN RatingUpdate p ON s.id = p.id AND s.carid = p.carid
WHERE s.design <> 'Honda5.0'
```